# Is it possible to assign the values from select exist query in MySQL to multiple variables in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

set sender_id = (Select EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `account` WHERE account_id = p_sender_id));

set viewer_id = (Select EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `account` WHERE account_id = p_viewer_id));

Comment: The sender_id  and viewer_id variable are in my stored procedure. I would like to use one query to set the values for the variables sender_id and viewer_id. I am checking if both values are present in my account table before I proceed to perform an insert into another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM account WHERE account_id = p_sender_id)),
       EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM account WHERE account_id = p_viewer_id))
INTO sender_id, viewer_id;
```

Read more about [SELECT...INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

---

Re your comment:

If you want to run one subquery to set both:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE account_id WHEN p_sender_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE account_id WHEN p_viewer_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
INTO sender_id, viewer_id 
FROM account
WHERE account_id IN (p_sender_id, p_viewer_id);
```

Comment: I tried using the SELECT INTO, but from that I have seen and tried, the query will have to be repeated. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without repeating the query?

Comment: The new query accomplished the what I wanted.